# InverseLaplaceTransform@LaplaceTransform does not reproduce the original expression

Tags: integral-transforms

```
In[1]:= InverseLaplaceTransform[LaplaceTransform[a^2/(a^2 + t^2), t, s], s, t]
Out[1]= 1/2 a InverseLaplaceTransform[(2 CosIntegral[a s] - Log[1/a^2] - 
  2 Log[a]) Sin[a s] + Cos[a s] (Sqrt[1/a^2] a \[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[a s]), s, t]
```

Or should I expect `InverseLaplaceTransform` can always recover the original expression?

Version: 11.2.0.0; Platform: Microsoft Windows (64-bit)

Comment: Try this:  `Assuming[ a > 0,
 InverseLaplaceTransform[ LaplaceTransform[ a^2 / (a^2 + t^2), t, s], s, t]
 ]`

Comment: @LouisB Good. You can write it as an answer and I will accept it.